# Fast Switching Windows Phone(7.8)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am a little bit confused if I need to really do anything for fast switching. It seems like if I am not using media element, camera and sockets I get this "fast switching" for free.

I am not sure how to test it though. I see a couple videos where

1. Hit the Windows Icon(Start Icon)
2. Hit the back button

or

1. Hold down the back button till you get the screen view
2. Go to some other app
3. Come back to your app.

These both seem to load up fast again but how about if.

1. Load up app
2. Hit windows icon
3. click on tile app

Should fast switching happen at this point or does it load a new instance of your app up killing your old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is different concept involved here:

-the first thing is Fast App resume which is a new feature of windows phone 8 that you can enable so that when you press the application tile it don't restart your app but keep the same instance (by default it will just kill the app and just recreate a new instance exactly as if the app was never opened). You can find more information about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

-the second concept is Fast App Switch and Tombstoning. You can find more information about the application life-cycle [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Basically what happen is when you press the windows button or navigate to another app your app will go in dormant state. In this state the application is not running but is still in memory. When you go back since everything is still in memory everything should as it was left off. The main case to handle in case of fast app switch is the fact that when your app is deactivated all the network connection are killed so you should make sure that when you go back you don't display any web error message dialog and that you redo any failed web request.

The second possible state of your application is that after the app is in dormant state you open a couple of app and the device don't have enough memory, then it will choose to tombstone your app. In that state your app is removed from memory so anything you have not saved will be lost. When you go back to your app it will go back to the page where the user previously was and recreate it. 
That mean that to handle this case before the app deactivate you should have :

- save any context specific data that you might not have been passing by navigation parameter.
- maybe save what the user have been currently doing (for example if he is currently entering a long text, it might be better to save it so that the user don't have to reenter it from scratch)
- saving the current scroll position or thing like selected items could be a plus

Also when the app resume you have to make sure that you re-query all information that you need. An example of something which would break would be if you load some Data (from a web server for example) in OnNavigatedTo of the main page and then just reuse the data on the detail page without re-querying it. If you are on the detail page press the start button and then do some other and the app tombstonne, when you go back to the app than the data will not be available (since the memory has been "cleared" and onNavigatedTo of the main page is not called since it will navigate back directly to the detail page).

You can use the [page state and application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to save whatever information you need to handle properly the tombstoning case. Basically there are dictionary to which you can add some object which will be serialize (so you need to make sure that whatever object you try to save is serialisable) automatically when the app is deactivated.

To test the Tombtonning case easily, what you can do is in the project properties, in the Debug Tab check the check box "Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging". Like this it will always tombstonne the app when you debug and  press the windows button or go to another app. To check that it is really tombstonning, when you go back you should see your app showing a resuming screen for a few second (while in the tombstonning case it's almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a bit confusing. It took me forever to figure out what they really mean by this.

What fast switching references is for more complicated apps. Apps that take advantage of something that requires a *saved state*.

For example if you are creating a navigation app. You are navigating then you leave the app. When you go back to that app it should show the "Resuming..." indicator and then bring your app back to its previous state.

Here is a Channel 9 video on FAS

http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/DVC09

Also here is the MSDN article about it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Should fast switching happen at this point or does it load a new instance of your app up killing your old one?

In that case, new instance of your would be launched.

Actually, its a bit confusing, but not that much.

- App can be either closed (by Windows key or pressing BAck key for a while) or exited (by pressing Back key in the main menu). Next, app comes to dormant state, it holds everything in memory. ApplicationDeactivated would be risen.
- So, if you would just re-activate it (by pressing Back and selecting your app, or by pressing Back only, if you have nothing else in the stack), it would be resumed. ApplicationActivated event would be risen with e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved = true
- If you would use lots of other apps (device would run out of memory), your app would go to tombstoned state. Then, you'd be needed to restore all data. e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved would be false.
- If you would re-launch your app (by clicking on tile), new instance would be launched, and ApplicationLaunching would be risen.

Comment: This is exactly what FAS is designed to prevent.

Comment: For example open Nokia Here Drive and choose a location then start navigating. Now hit the home button. Now click on the tile and open the app. Nokia Here Drive doesn't restart. It uses a tombstoned state to FAS or fast app switch back into your app.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry, its wp8 feature. I'm using wp7 only.

Comment: @AMR wait.. but the question was about 7.8 :)

Comment: FAS was known as Tombstoning in 7.1 and 7.8 it exists

Comment: @AMR Not sure. As it is said on your link,

Comment: If the app is suspended and the user relaunches the app, such as by tapping on the app name in the app list or tapping the app’s primary Start Tile, by default the old instance of the app is terminated and a brand new instance of the app is created. This process is slower than resuming a suspended app and provides a different user experience. Windows Phone 8 introduces the ability for apps to request that user actions that would typically relaunch the app, such as tapping the app’s Start Tile, instead resume the suspended instance of the suspended app instance, if one exists

Comment: So, FAS is "extended version" of Tombstoning, which is added in WP8. It adds possibility to re-run app faster. So, FAS is not avaivable at wp7? Also, it needs ActivationPolicy.

Comment: FAS is just another name for tombstoning. They do almost identical things. The difference is the implementation. WP8 makes it easier.

Comment: Still confused in the challange I am doing it states 
    Support Windows Phone 8, Windows Phone 7.8, or both.
    Follow the Windows Phone UI Guidelines.
    Employ Fast App Switching.
    Include all 3 sizes of Tiles.
What do they mean by Fast App Switching in WP7.8(not doing Wp8) as from what I saw on Google was it's handled by default for you.

Comment: @chobo2 If i were you, i'd listen to Mark Sowul. He recommends to do everything yourself. Like i described, its not that huge amount of states. Just save everything in ApplicationDeactivated, check IsApplicationInstancePreserved  in the ApplicationActivated, so you would know, if you should restore saved data.

Answer (score 0):

Fast switching isn't something that really concerns you as a developer.  What you need to worry about is "tombstoning" - when someone switches away from your app, you need to save the state: when the user switches back to it, you as the developer have to assume that your app was actually *restarted from scratch* and needs to *reload* that saved state. That's the difference between `Application_Launching` and `Application_Activated` (user started your app anew from the start screen, vs. app was suspended and is now being resumed, but from scratch).

At some earlier point this was the only way app switching worked.  Fast App Switching was added later on and simply changed the contract such that sometimes your app would be resumed where it left off without being tombstoned.  It depends on memory, etc, but it is simply a benefit to the user who will, in many cases, no longer need to wait for the app to reload its tombstoned state.  You as the developer still have to assume you'll be tombstoned.

Comment: Ok,some requirement in a challenge I want to do specifically stated must have "fast switching" but after my research it seems like it was automatic so I got confused. With tombstoning how do you handle multiple pages(user could be on Page 5 and it's state needs to be restored another might be on Page 2 and need a restore). Is everything being handled in that one method? Also if your using MVVM how does that all work(this could be a separate question).

Comment: The OS will be reloading whatever page the user left off. If they were on Page 5 when they went away, the app will be loaded at Page 5.  See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548.aspx

Comment: Even if it is tomb stoned it will load Page 5 right away up full with constructor?